# Web UI components using go template

Tags: go

I am new to go template. I was wondering whether we can use go template to build generic reusable web UI components, for example tree components (using go html template), which can later be used across the project. Has any one tried it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can, but note that templates are executed at server side. Check out the `{{define}}`, `{{block}}` and `{{template}}` actions.

Comment: Can you elaborate or point to some sample example where it is implemented? i am looking to build kind of dumb web client, everything will be derived from server using go template (htmx)